# Render form with ajax submit

Tags: ajax, forms

I have a custom form in a module, similar to this example:

```
function mymodule_form($form, &$form_state) {
   $radio_options = array(...);
   $form = array();
   $form["wrapper"] = array("#markup" => "<div id='test-ajax'></div>");
   $form['choice'] = array(
       '#title' => '',
       '#type' => 'radios',
       '#options' => $radio_options,
   );
   $form['submit'] = array(
       '#type' => 'submit',
       '#value' => t('Vote'),
       '#ajax' => array(
           'callback' => 'demo_form_ajax_submit',
           'wrapper' => "test-ajax",
           'method' => 'replace',
           'effect' => 'fade',
       ),
   ); 
   return $form;
}

function demo_form_ajax_submit($form, $form_state) {
   var_dump("something");
}
```

And I'm printing that form in template like this:

```
<div class='row'>
   <?php print render($form['choice']); ?>
   <?php print render($form['form_build_id']); ?>
   <?php print render($form['form_token']); ?>
   <?php print render($form['form_id']); ?>
   <?php print render($form['submit']) ?>
</div>
```

The form is printed correctly and even the button shows the ajax icon when clicked, but it does not work. When I check the logs it shows 2 errors:

- Notice: Undefined index: `form_build_id in ajax_get_form()` (line 325 of...
- Invalid form POST data.

It is similar to this issue [Ajax not working for themed form](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/79562/ajax-not-working-for-themed-form) but it does not work even adding `drupal_render_children($form);` at the bottom of the template.

Notes:

- I added `drupal_add_library('system', 'drupal.ajax');` in the module.
- I'm using jQuery 1.7
- I also tested `drupal_render()` instead of `render()`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of print rendering the individual items, you can try to build your form using the [drupal_get_form](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/drupal_get_form/7) core function, which allows Drupal to add all the extra components to the form (including the Ajax call).

So in your template it would like like this:

```
$output = drupal_get_form('mymodule_form');
print drupal_render($output);
```

Comment: I need to print the elements separately in order to theming them. I tried that way printing the elements separately para I got the same issues above.

Comment: @JoseDaniel You can theme the elements separately using form_alter. Are you saying that you did try the drupal_get_form? If yes, what happens - does the form render properly?

Comment: If I printed the way you said (drupal_render($output)), it prints the html of the form and it works, but I need to print each element separately in order to theme them and put the elements in different places.

I also tried to print drupal_render($output['name_of_the_element']) as my example above, but I got the same issues.

What is your solution with form_alter? Thanks!

Comment: @JoseDaniel so if you use drupal_render($output) does the Ajax call work? Re theming, look at this [tutorial](https://www.drupal.org/node/651106) so you can do something like: `function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
 if($form_id == 'your_form_id') {
    // modify  your form fields here
 }
}`

Comment: I see, but it does not solve my problem. I don't need to modify the elements, I need to render them separately in the template.

Comment: Ah I see. Out of curiosity, what is the reason you need to render the elements separately? And let me know if Ajax worked when you used drupal_get_form... this will help figure out where the bug is